# Doctrine is freaking out when I turn on php opcache on

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, opcache

I'm having a really strange problem with Doctrine and `PHP 5.5.6 Opcache`. Everything is working just fine when the `opcache` module is turned off. Once I turn it on, I begin getting the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class "Admin\Models\Users\Role" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 336
( ! ) Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class "Admin\Models\Users\Role" is not a valid entity or mapped super class. in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 336
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  128016  {main}( )   ../app.php:0
2   0.0185  615020  Core\Bootstrap->handle( )   ../app.php:53
3   0.0210  695744  call_user_func_array ( )    ../Bootstrap.php:111
4   0.0210  695976  Admin\Controllers\DashboardController->indexAction( )   ../Bootstrap.php:111
5   0.0210  696028  Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository( )    ../DashboardController.php:25
6   0.0210  696072  Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository( )  ../EntityManager.php:759
7   0.0210  696176  Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->createRepository( )   ../DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:50
8   0.0210  696200  Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata( ) ../DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:67
9   0.0210  696420  Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( ) ../EntityManager.php:295
10  0.0213  699628  Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata( )   ../AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:211
11  0.0224  781128  Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata( )    ../AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:318
12  0.0224  782824  Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass( )   ../ClassMetadataFactory.php:117
```

I believe my entities are defined properly - as I mentioned in the beginning, once I disable opcache everything works as expected. To initialize Doctrine I'm using this piece of code:

```
// $this->getEntityPaths()   returns an array of existing absolute paths, each of which is checked with realpath().
// $this->getProxyPath()     returns a string with the absolute path, checked with realpath()
// $this->getInDevelopment() returns boolean and is set to TRUE


$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($this->getEntityPaths(), $this->getInDevelopment(), $this->getProxyPath());
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);

$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_pgsql',
    'host'     => $this->getHost(),
    'port'     => $this->getPort(),
    'user'     => $this->getUser(),
    'password' => $this->getPass(),
    'dbname'   => $this->getName()
);

$this->db = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

I've also tried this configuration:

```
$config = new Configuration;
$config->setProxyDir($this->getProxyPath());
$config->setProxyNamespace('DoctrineProxies');
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);

$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($this->getEntityPaths());

$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());
$config->setQueryCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_pgsql',
    'host'     => $this->host,
    'port'     => $this->port,
    'user'     => $this->user,
    'password' => $this->pass,
    'dbname'   => $this->name
);

$this->db = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Here is the entity

```
/**
 * Roles
 *
 * @Table(name="roles")
 * @Entity
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="role_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $role_id;


    /**
     * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I have `AutoGenerateProxyClasses` on, but just to be sure I've also tested it by generating the proxies. Unfortunately I get the same exception. I'm not sure how to pursue this problem and what exactly IS the problem. Is it a Doctrine bug? Why having `OpCache` turned on results in `Doctrine` exceptions and having it off works fine? Have I missed something in the configuration part or the entity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I finally managed to understand why Doctrine was not working right with OpCache set on. Apparently by default opcache does not store or load any comments you have in your php file. As you can imagine, this results in tons of unexplained exceptions in any php library which relies on Annotations. So just go to your `php.ini`, change the lines below and you'll be as good as new. I guess this should go into the Doctrine help as well.

```
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.load_comments=1
```

Comment: If I add this two lines in php.ini will this inbuilt opcache serve the purpose for doctrine2 or I have to install APCu separately? As far I know opcache is not full blown cache like APCu.

Comment: It depends on your case - if the platform you're working on has heavy traffic, you might want to use `Memcache`. Otherwise you should be  ok with only `Opcache`

Comment: As per my knowledge and doctrine documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html, we have only following drivers: 1. $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache(); 2. $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache(); 3. $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache(); $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\XcacheCache(); 4. $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache(); 5. $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache(); Any Idea which driver will work work with inbuilt opcache.

Comment: `Opcache` pre-compiles your scripts into bytecode and stores it in shared memory. On every next request, php serves the script from shared memory instead of compiling it again. It does only that - you can't store any `key=>val` data like you could with `APC` or `Memcache`. So, if you're only using `Opcache` you'll need the `ArrayCache` driver which stores the cache in a `php` file on your file system. That file will also be pre-compiled into bytecode and stored in shared memory.