# How to use APC cache with doctrine2 after php version 5.4

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, apc, opcache

I am using APC cache for doctrine2, configured while bootstrapping:

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;

$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setResultCacheImpl($cache);
```

And configuration for php.ini:

```
[APC]
apc.shm_size = '128M'
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.num_files_hint=0
apc.user_entries_hint=0
apc.ttl=0
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.stat=1
apc.enable_cli=0
apc.file_update_protection=2
apc.max_file_size=2M
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.use_request_time=1
apc.slam_defense=0
apc.stat_ctime=0
apc.canonicalize=1
apc.write_lock=1
apc.report_autofilter=0
apc.rfc1867=0
apc.rfc1867_prefix =upload_
apc.rfc1867_name=APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_freq=0
apc.rfc1867_ttl=3600
apc.lazy_classes=0
apc.lazy_functions=0
```

APC cache dll extension for PHP is available upto php version 5.4
After 5.4 an inbuilt extension is available as an opcache but how to use it with doctrine2?

Comment: If you really need apc with php > 5.4, you can use https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu

Comment: Ok great! I will try php_apcu.dll and seems that it will work. Do you know that why can't we use opcache instead of APC builtin in php.5.5 and higher versions?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be a problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21925354/569101 or http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-opcache/

Comment: Ok great, I have read the links you mentioned. Just one doubt will this line of code remains the same if I use opcache instead of APC: $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;

Comment: Of course not. But regarding [an other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18042566/569101) you should use apcu since opcache *is a simply opcode cache*.

Comment: So the conclusion is that we cannot use opcache with doctrine instead of APC/APCu.